# Remove HDMI monitor build-in sound output

Tags: audio, hdmi, macos-sierra

I connect iiyama ProLite X2483HSU monitor via HDMI. This monitor has built-in speakers. I don't need this option, even if it worked. I want to remove this device from Audio MIDI Setup, so that it stops showing up in sound output options or defaulting to this device, which sometimes happens for an unknown reason. It shows up in the output dropdown as PLX2483H. I use internal speakers, jack, or AirPlay.

I can't remove this device from Audio MIDI Setup menu - the `-` button is inactive. I've already searched in `/System/Library/Extensions/`, `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/`, `~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/`, `ps aux`, `top`, but couldn't find anything related. Is it possible at all to remove / disable this device / option?

Comment: Does changing the audio input to Line in via the monitor's OSD menu have any effect on the way the computer recognizes the the monitor?

Comment: There are two options in the OSD menu Audio sections: `HDMI` and `Line-In`. Changing between them has no effect on how my MacBook Pro detects the monitor.